# Textbox is not empty even when I delete contents and click update

Tags: javascript, html

[image]

I have a Wishlist page with a comment box to add notes to it.  When there is no text, it says "Add your notes here..." in the gray text like the 4th product.  When you write a note, you go to Update Wishlist btn and click it to update what note you wrote.  This works.  What doesn't work is that when you already have a note added and you delete the text and click the update wishlist btn, it doesn't revert to "Add your notes here".  It stays the same.  I have written a comment for the first 3 input boxes, the 4th is blank.

However, if there is an update on the comment box and you change it from "testing1" to "testing123456" then click the Update Wishlist btn, it works.  If the text is "texting1" and I delete the text and only press the spacebar, the input box will be completely blank (obviously the space counts).  Just a notice, the red (x) button on the top right of each product is to take off a product from the Wishlist page which works, the Update Wishlist btn is the button I use every time I need to make a change in the comment section.

Thank you for your time!

```
<textarea type="text" placeholder="Add your notes here..." class="searchBox" title="Comment" name="description[<?php echo $item->getWishlistItemId() ?>]" 
rows="3" cols="5" style="width:700px; min-height: 80px; margin-bottom: 5px;">
<?php echo ($this->escapeHtml($item->getDescription())) ?>
</textarea>
```

Comment: Where is the corresponding javascript code that you've written..? Are we supposed to do this from scratch..?

Comment: @TJ Just thinking out loud here. Would this need some javascript or would it have to do with the page/code the "Update Wishlist" button uses ? If its updating it when there is text then maybe its a problem with the table where it doesn't accept empty values ?

Comment: Are you doing this using php? i'm not familiar with php. if you're doing this using js then posting the js would help..

Comment: @TJ I think he's using PHP. He uses <?php echo ($this->escapeHtml($item->getDescription())) ?> to pull the comment from the table for each product.